# C# file from streamReader split into int and string by space. after first line

Tags: c#

So what I'm trying to do is read a text file that will have just a month on the first line, every line after having a year space then month.

in the example the first line says march which I need to be able to save to compare to the rest of the months, so i need to split every line after march by space only.

```
readContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            string[] lines = readContents.Split('\r');
```

Ive been playing around with variations of this code with no success, any help is appreciated.

[image]

added an img of the text file but heres also what it would say 
incase the formate changes, the first line says March, every line after starts with a year then a space then a month, one perline.

```
march
1998    january
2010    october
1990    november
0
```

Comment: could you paste an example of your text file?

Comment: Do you have to use `StreamReader`? You could use `File.ReadAllLines` to get an array of individual lines, then if it contains a space, split it based on the spaces.

Comment: just paste a part of it into your question

Comment: I could do it without without streamReader as long as i can compare my months to the first line

Comment: I think you should explain what are the parameters and the desired outcome of this comparison. The tools used may depend on it and change accordingly.

Comment: I would like to able to change first line month and compare it to the rest of the text file, so that I can say iif(month==month) **(date >=1990 && date <== 2000){